# Sending and receiving data via tcp sockets to a remote running process in Dart

Tags: sockets, dart, tcp, process.start

Just mucking around with Dart at the moment to try to create a simple use case. The goal is to run a command-line process of choice on a Windows system and then interact with it remotely via a standard tcp socket. Essentially I'm running a compiled Dart binary on a Windows box and listening for the response on a Linux box.

This is where my slowly-forming code is at:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() async {
   Socket s = await Socket.connect("192.168.1.2", 8000);
   var process = await Process.start("cmd.exe", []);
   process.stdout
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .listen((output) { s.write(output); s.flush(); });
        stdin.pipe(s.stdin);
```

Running the compiled binary of this code on the host sends the cmd prompt to my listener, but won't accept any commands coming from the listener (which I obviously want to execute within the selected process). I can enter the commands on the host and they'll happily send through to the listener, but I'm stuck on how to get data entered on the remote host-side of the connection to be sent via the socket and executed by the process, with the response returned.

My problem here is that I'm reading stdin for the process (ie. stdin.pipe(s.stdin) on line 11), which is why whatever I type on the host is executed and returned to the listener, but I need the socket to listen for data from the listener, feed it to the process, then return the output back to the listener via the socket. Easy enough in my head, just not in Dart!

I've checked out https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.1/dart-io/dart-io-library.html and a range of other resources looking for examples of integrating process.start with tcp sockets. There are plenty of examples of client/server code but nothing that integrates a native process into the mix in the way that I'm looking at.

Keen for suggestions/pointers.

Thx,
Sauce